# Reposition objects in multiple SVG files

Tags: linux, automation, vector-graphics

I've been making a vector animation by creating separate SVG file for each frame in Inkscape. While making one of the frames I realized that I don't have enough space on the canvas to fit the top of an image. How can I move objects down in every file by a specified value, so I don't need to do this by hand for every frame?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a feature of SVG in general or of the format generated by Inkscape, but there are parameters "viewport", "height" and "width" that can be modified with sed to resize and reposition the entire picture.